# cummulative query not working when there is no data specific date,month

Tags: mysql, sql

```
==============================
ID1 |ID2|ID3 |  Date    |count|
==============================|
1   |a  |b   |01-01-2014|   10|
1   |a  |b   |18-06-2014|   0 |
1   |b  |d   |01-01-2014|   10|
1   |b  |d   |01-02-2014|   5 |
1   |d  |ed  |01-02-2014|   15|
1   |d  |ed  |18-06-2014|   0 |
2   |e  |abc5|02-01-2014|   5 |
2   |e  |abc5|03-01-2014|   5 |
2   |e  |abc6|25-06-2014|   5 |
2   |e  |abc7|21-01-2014|   25| 
3   |b  |d   |01-01-2014|   10|
3   |b  |d   |01-02-2014|   5 |
===============================
```

Query used as below:

```
select id1,tmesg 
from (
       select    id1,id2,id3,count,date, 
                 (a.count + COALESCE((select sum(b.count) 
                                      from   table_test b 
                                      where b.date < a.date 
                                      and  b.id1= a.id1 
                                      and b.id2 = a.id2 
                                      and b.id3 = a.id3 
                                      group by id1,id2,id3),0)) as tmesg
      from table_test a where  date ='2014-08-01'  order by id1,id2,id3) z

group by id1,tmesg
```

The cumulative output should be as below:

```
1   40
2   40
3   15
```

if it is <2014-08-01. it should cumulative and give the result up to available max date.

Comment: The string '2014-08-01' != '01-08-2014'. It seems that this could be one reason for your trouble.

Comment: It more depends on the setting of date format at client side..This is not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I can not understand why the query is not just:

```
select id1, sum(count)
from table_test
where date < '2014-08-01' 
group by id1
```

This produces the output you want from your sample data

Comment: agreed. The OP's query is running a sub-query for *every* record in the table. This answer provides a much more efficient and readable approach

Comment: As a user I can give dates as input as shown in where condition with the operators on or before specific date, on or after specific  date, equal to specific date. In our example case as above, the condition operator is equal to specific date. Since, ID1, ID2, ID3 are not unique in the above table, we will have to use them in join conditions and get cumulative count as given in above query.

Comment: @Krishna no, you don't need to join. nothing in your question says that id2 and id3 are relevant - just ignore them. vary your date range logic, but the sum and group by are all you need otherwise.

Comment: Even, if I do not join them, I do not get the result expected on that day. I want to know the cumulative count of ID1 specific to date. The query should give expected cumulative result even if I give equality condition. In our case, it would give zero result. As on 2014-08-01, we do not have any records. But, as on 2014-08-01, the cumulative of 1 is 40, 2 is 40 and 3 is 15 in our example case.

Comment: Run the query and see what it does

Comment: I did ran the query with equality operator and the result is not same as mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:

Based on the clarification from OP that the query needs to be able to return output regardless of the operator used, I have rewritten the query, as below:

**Notes**

`max_dates` returns the maximum date for each id1 based on the following rules:

1 if there is 1 or more rows returned by the condition (e.g. < '2014-08-01'), then the maximum date out of those rows is returned.

2 if there are no rows returned by the condition, then the maximum date based on ALL rows for that id1 is returned

```
select
    cd.id1,
    cd.count_dt,
    (select sum(b.count_no) 
    from counts_date b 
    where b.id1 = max_dates.id1 
    and b.count_dt <= cd.count_dt
    ) as t_mesg
from counts_date cd
inner join
    (select
        all_id1.id1 id1,
        COALESCE(max(a.count_dt), (select max(count_dt) from counts_date b where b.id1=all_id1.id1)) max_dt
    from counts_date a
    right join
    (select distinct id1 from counts_date) all_id1
    on a.id1 = all_id1.id1 and a.count_dt > '2014-09-02'
    group by all_id1.id1
    ) max_dates
on cd.id1= max_dates.id1 and cd.count_dt <= max_dates.max_dt
group by cd.id1, cd.count_dt
order by cd.id1, cd.count_dt;
```

The query returns the cumulative sum for each date. If only the sum is required, then the query can be modified, as below:

```
select
    cd.id1,
    sum(cd.count_no) t_mesg
from counts_date cd
inner join
    (select
        all_id1.id1 id1,
        COALESCE(max(a.count_dt), (select max(count_dt) from counts_date b where b.id1=all_id1.id1)) max_dt
    from counts_date a
    right join
    (select distinct id1 from counts_date) all_id1
    on a.id1 = all_id1.id1 and a.count_dt < '2014-02-02'
    group by all_id1.id1
    ) max_dates
on cd.id1= max_dates.id1 and cd.count_dt <= max_dates.max_dt
group by cd.id1
order by cd.id1;
```

The **updated** <kbd>[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86812/81)</kbd> illustrates the working of both the queries.

**Reference**:

[Fetch cumulative sum from MySQL table on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16322133/fetch-cumulative-sum-from-mysql-table)

Comment: Please check other comments posted. The operator can be any thing depending on the user/report selection. In the example shown, I can give equality condition and expected output should be same.

Comment: Are you saying that instead of `< '2014-08-01'`, it could be `= '2014-08-01'` or `> '2014-08-01'`?

Comment: @Krishna Please see modified queries above. You can use different operators and date values to still obtain expected output.

Comment: I will check this and revert.

Comment: The first query is not working in postgres database. it works in sqlfiddle. It returns the error. ERROR: subquery uses ungrouped column "max_dates.id1" from outer query. The second query, can we have date column also.. the max(date). Please let me know.

Comment: I added the column alias for id1 within `max_dates`. The second query is the same as the query without the date column. So, if you need the date column, just use the 1st query. The queries have been tested with MySQL. Is your database MySQL or Postgres?

Comment: It is Postgres Joseph. I agree, it works in mysql and oracle and not in postgres.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for flexibility in creating the date range. BETWEEN can handle this pretty well, without any loss in efficiency.

Pass in a start and an end date, using the minimum and maximum dates as needed. You can handle the different use cases as follows...

**on or before**:

```
SELECT id1, sum(count)
FROM table_test
WHERE date BETWEEN '0000-00-00' AND '2014-08-01' 
GROUP BY id1
```

**on**:

```
SELECT id1, sum(count)
FROM table_test
WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-08-01' AND '2014-08-01' 
GROUP BY id1
```

**on or after**:

```
SELECT id1, sum(count)
FROM table_test
WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-08-01' AND '9999-12-31' 
GROUP BY id1
```

**after**:

```
SELECT id1, sum(count)
FROM table_test
WHERE date BETWEEN date_add('2014-08-01', INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND '9999-12-31' 
GROUP BY id1
```

This is a much cleaner approach than trying to devise a query where different operators get the same result.

Comment: The query will not give the expected result as shown above for on operator or after operator. I am looking for cumulative count depending on the conditions mentioned.

Comment: You should be handling your "operator" conditions in the UI, not in the query. The = and > operators mean two different things; you should not be trying to force them to give the same result in the backend

Comment: The query I mentioned as sample is the closest one. But, the problem is, it would not count, if there is no record for specific period. it expects a mandatory record with atleast 0 value. I am looking for other alternatives. The report/jasper manages the operators, but we need cumulative result through query.